# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer to **accept/decline** the nomination. Nominees: please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="http://ai.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://ai.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Answer (score 23):

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Currently most voted and dedicated user with the relevant knowledge and skills about AI. In addition, he's working in this research area, so he knows what he's talking about. His skills may help to improve quality of this site.

EDIT by NietzscheanAI (formerly known as user217281728): 
Most kind, thanks. I'm happy to accept this nomination and want to work to make this a informative and useful site. I live in the UK, so tend to be active on the site between 07.00 and 23.00 GMT. My varied career has included games software company owner, generative music developer, software architect, pure mathematician and (for the last 13 years) AI researcher.

Comment: Wow, 64 answers (and counting, hopefully). We have a topic expert right here.

Comment: I edited the nomination to include the nominee's network-wide flair.

Comment: @user217281728 Are you from London?

Comment: @kenorb No, I'm not.

Comment: @user217281728 Get a fancier username maybe?

Comment: @Rahul2001 - better?

Comment: @NietzscheanAI YES!

Comment: 'e' constant was fancier I think:)

Comment: @NietzscheanAI just a note: I'm glad you're not a randomly anonymous who-knows-what-he-is-doing AI enthusiast from Russia or whatever :) I mean, because of the lack of information on your profile, sometimes I was playing with such thoughts, but of course it was not a serious issue, but rather some joke in my head.

Comment: Dear NietzscheanAI, considering the votes, I think we can welcome you in the mod club. As you finally get the diamond, please don't forget: as the site matures and grows older, its standards and customs tend to differ more and more from the common sense, and it results a growing ratio of disappointed newbies, leaving the site after their closed first questions. Please pay attention for that! Many SE sites has fallen already in this trap. Thanks!

Comment: @peterh - I'm not an enthusiastic closer of questions.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

The second most voted and active user, data scientist with the right skillset across different AI branches. His answers are reliable and interesting. His skills can be a great asset to improve quality of this site.

EDIT by Matthew Graves: Thanks for the nomination! I'm pleased to accept it. I'm interested in helping this site help people better understand AI and the issues surrounding it, both through direct effort and community building. I've been clearing out review queues here as soon as I got access to them, and that's typically the first thing I check after my comment inbox.

I'm currently in Austin, Texas, and so would typically be online from to about noon to 2am UTC. I've been doing machine-learning related work for, depending on how you count it, about 8 years now, mostly as a student but now also as a data scientist. My research effort has mostly been in numerical optimization, machine reliability, and time series analysis, rounded out by my personal interests in psychology, economics, and philosophy. I've been interested in intelligence for as long as I can remember, and that grew to encompass artificial intelligence as soon as I was introduced to it.

To a large degree I 'grew up on the internet'; forum-posting has been a major hobby for over half of my life at this point. I've consistently had a reputation for being polite, calm, and open-minded; qualities that I hope would serve me well as a moderator.

Comment: I edited the nomination to include the nominee's network-wide flair.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because of his active involvement in the community's development during the private beta and his experience on Stack Exchange!

I'll step right up and offer my services to the community as a moderator pro tempore. I confess that I'm just an enthusiast when it comes to artificial intelligence, but I have been highly active here on meta, gaining the community's first silver badge: [Convention](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/badges/68/convention). I thoroughly enjoy reviewing and I have been working the queues since the site's beginning. I've also spent a large (probably unhealthy, heh) amount of time reading Meta Stack Exchange and the SE blogs, so I'm familiar with the Stack Exchange model, the software, and the expectations for the various roles. I'm also active on [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/users/380318/ben-n?tab=topactivity), for what it's worth.

I live in Illinois (midwestern United States), so I'm usually awake from UTC 15:00 to 3:00. You can read about the things I've created in my profile. I have a blog [on which I mentioned the site a while back](https://fleexlab.blogspot.com/2016/08/ai-stack-exchange-site.html).

I've been doing what I can to make sure this site survives, and that has required casting a few close votes. Hopefully I haven't come off as too much of a maniacal ruthless reviewer `:)`. When asked on meta, in comments, or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43371/artificial-intelligence) about why a question is closed, I always write up a helpful, respectful explanation. If I ever do something you think is less than ideal, please feel free to ask me about it! Like all humans (though perhaps not AIs!) I make the occasional mistake, and when I see that's happened, I make it right.

I have my own opinions and judgments, of course, but I would be happy to carry out as moderator pro tempore the consensus of the community, the mod team, and Stack Exchange. We're all in this together.

It's a pleasure building this community with everyone here. I look forward to continuing to the next stage of site growth with y'all!

Comment: Full disclosure: it looks like one of the people from Super User's Root Access chat room joined the site and only upvoted this. I had linked the site's Area 51 proposal to drum up traffic for the site, not votes for myself. I apologize for the slight score inflation. On the plus side, we do have a handful of new users from SU looking around our main!

Comment: ^ That comment alone speaks volumes. Diamond this man. (Also active on main meta, which is worth having in a mod.)

Comment: Would you mind cleaning up this thread to fix the broken flairs? (I don't have edit privs, and you're like the only one I know still hangs out on Meta...)

Answer (score 12):

[image]

[image]

[image: profile for Mithrandir on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

#### Notes:

I would like to offer my services as a pro-tem moderator on this site. I have watched been a relatively active member since I joined on Day 0. I have 135 edits (counting tag-only edits), I was the first one to earn the [Strunk and White badge](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white), I am the top reviewer for both [Close Votes](https://ai.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) and [Reopen Votes](https://ai.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/stats) on the main site, I was the first reviewer of [Late Answers](https://ai.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/stats),  and I was the first reviewer on Meta. I have watched Meta, and pitched in when I could.
I was also one of 25 users to earn the [Beta badge](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta), which means that I was an active user in the Private Beta. I now also have the [Convention badge](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/badges/68/convention), which means that I've been active here on Meta.
 I may not know so much about AI, really, but I do know enough to be able to tell if something answers the question or not, I think. :)

Also, I am one of the only users who has ventured onto [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43371/the-singularity) :P

I am also active on this Meta, the Puzzling Meta, and the main Meta*.

I am fairly well-versed in the content in the Help Center and site policy, as well.

<sub>* Okay, I mostly flag things as off-topic. But I have asked/answered some!</sub>

**About Me**

I'm a 14 year-old kid. The only moderation experience I have is being an admin on 3 Wikias. (Not popular ones - little outdated backwater ones. :P) I live in the UTC+2/3 time zone, although I'm often on late.
I don't go to school; I'm homeschooled.
I am not a programmer.
I have been using SE for a year and 11 months, roughly, so I have a pretty good idea about how the site works :P.

Comment: This is how I know this guy: Edited by Mithrandir. I keep seeing it on multiple SE sites.

Comment: @CemKalyoncu :P I like editing.

Comment: I told ya, someone is [on editing spree](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/37632?m=31055637#31055637) ;D

Comment: Yes, but he has it as CM & SE employee. These rules bind his hands: he can't do elected mod tasks, his role is essentially an over-mod exception handler. Being an elected mod, this rules wouldn't bind his hands.

Answer (score 6):

I'll volunteer myself.

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because - he is passionate about AI and its potential applications for improving the human condition.  This nominee is also a strong supporter of open exchange of scientific knowledge and technology, as expressed in the Open Source, Open Web, Open Data, Open Science and Open Hardware initiatives.   This nominee has been participating in multiple Stack Exchange communities for many years.

You could consider this nominee to be the "ruthless NON closer" as he believes that closing questions is generally harmful to the community, as it is perceived as an aggressive and hostile act by whoever posted the question.  This nominee believes that "bad" questions can simply be down-voted and allowed to die from lack of activity in *almost* all cases.

This nominee believes we can strike a balance between being "beginner friendly" and still keeping things interesting enough to attract experts, but believes that it will take some time to establish our presence in the AI world and attract the high-level researchers and others of that ilk.

---

Since I volunteered myself, it should go without saying that I accept this nomination.

Hi, I am Phillip. I live in Chapel Hill, NC, so I am generally active on this site from around 10:00am through 1:00am Eastern time. Some other things you may want to know about me are: I am founder / president at [Fogbeam Labs](https://www.fogbeam.com), an open source software company.  I was a volunteer firefighter for many years and was Assistant Fire Chief of my department for the last couple of years I was there.

I am the founder/organizer of the Research Triangle Park "Semantic Web / Artificial Intelligence / Machine Learning" Meetup here in the Raleigh/Durham area.  I'm also active on [Github](http://mindcrime.github.io) and [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/user?id=mindcrime).

Comment: I edited the nomination to include your meta flair, and make the flair actually match the link it goes to.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

---

#### Notes:

While I'm not the most knowledgeable about AI, and don't have the highest reputation level, I know a lot about moderating.

In the past three days, every single day, I've cleared all the review ques I have access to. I currently own two organizations, and I moderate, or lead, both of them. I have 2 pending proposals on Area51. I'm active on the Stack Exchange sites almost every single day. I have former experience from moderating as a former FPC from Scratch.

It would be an honor to be a moderator on this site.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: " I'm not the most knowledgeable about AI". How much do you know?

Comment: @ABcDexter About what? AI is a rather large subject. You could be talking about neural networks, the history/origin of AI, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because kenorb is a very active user, a person who knows a lot about AI, and, I feel, cares about helping this community grow. kenorb should be one of our moderators - even if his English isn't perfect, I still think he's perfect mod material. :)

---

First of all, I would like to thank you for nomination and I am pleased to take the responsibility of being a pro tempore mod. I believe that this site has a unique opportunity to make a huge impact to global technology market driven by artificial intelligence and our everyday life in the very near future by sharing advanced knowledge accessible for all.

I have been using SE for over 7 years, I am experienced across a variety of fields and I am familiar with moderation tools and I understand their purpose.

I am an experienced software engineer specialising in a variety of information technology stacks with over 18 years experience consulting across a range of sectors and multination companies. One of the recent one is planning to ['to deploy drone army'](http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/5ea4c668-1364-11e6-91da-096d89bd2173.html#axzz4HXDwufht) worldwide which can expand our scope of understanding of artificial intelligence (e.g. imagine flying drones in the restaurant and delivering your food to your table after pressing a single button). Check also my [user CV profile](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/kenorb).

My first AI program was a chat bot written over 18 years ago in Pascal with custom written assembler libraries in order to make my school mates believing that they are chatting on IRC with real people, while being on the computers without any internet connection, so other can play games on spare computers with the real network. This worked, for the first 15-30 minutes, later on they could find out that something was wrong or get bored. Second project was involved AI bots protecting IRC channels. I did some AI in games. Since then I am interested in practical applications of AI. This is my long term hobby and interest. Further projects required more sophisticated requirements. Currently I am working on integration AI with the financial algorithms and systems.

I am good team player, so I am able to cooperate with other mods, I'm also available on daily basis (GMT/DST time). I hope we can improve this site by keeping it away from chaos, spam and trolls, to provide high quality site.

Comment: I edited the nomination to include the nominee's network-wide flair.

Comment: I personally think Kenorb is the best one for this. But, the community's response made me scratch my head :(

Comment: I could guess that some science people didn't like the general approach of this AI site treating it as a competition hoping it'll fail again in favor of Stats.SE, CS.SE or DataScience.SE, so negativity was expected, therefore I didn't expect to have a lot of fans. I think every success require some conflicts, sacrifices and hard work, so I'm really happy that this site went beta after 6 years of constant failures. I hope this will serve humanity for the next 100+ years to keep up with so much changing world and sharing the advanced knowledge to everyone.

Comment: @kenorb I doubt it's because "science people didn't like you". More likely, I'm afraid to say, that the community doesn't think you're mod material.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Thanks for your honest opinion:) Any idea about specifics?

Comment: @kenorb You had said: `I am >7 year old SE user experienced across variety of fields and I am familiar with moderation tools and understanding their purpose`

Comment: @Mithrandir True, my EN is still bad despite few Cambridge-FCE-like certificates (theory != practice), secondly usually I'm in hurry when writing and all the time distracted couple of times, so I had to re-read everything what I wrote couple of times, but even this doesn't help:) But not everybody is so pedantic to the English. So I don't think that's the reason, usually people just doesn't like me, since I tend to draw a lot of controversies whatever I do while pushing the things forward:)

Comment: What the hell is with all the downvotes?!

Comment: Why the downvotes o.O

Comment: @ABcDexter I honestly don't know.

Comment: Yes, if someone doesn't like the nomination, say it openly. One must be honest, just like ArtofCode explained...

Comment: @Mithrandir Actually i read everything, but am not sure about anyone. If mod pro tempore is chosen from a set of experts, it would be great ^_^

Comment: I have downvoted this nomination because while kenorb seems to claim he has worked for a lot of years in the AI field, his questions and answers on this site appear to be based on very shaky ground and sometimes are borderline cranky. Moreover I have seen kenorb repeatedly use very dubious sources to justify his claims on other SE sites. His line of defence here is "Science people don't like me" which again sounds very cranky.

Comment: @Fatalize This is how I work, questioning everything and seeing everything from the different point of view. My approach is to analyse concepts based on my logical conclusions given the available data (that is not by repeating what the mainstream or other says) and I see nothing wrong with it. This is how the real science work, building and organising knowledge, not assuming that a single body-of-knowledge has the ultimate truth. If we would believe in mainstream all the time, we'll still live on the flat Earth. Although the A.I. science is very simple, it's testable and it needs to work.

Comment: @kenorb Just visited this site for the first time. Net score was 0, so I upvoted you.

Comment: @user1271772 Thanks, appreciate that, now I've got +14 vs -13:) Most of the candidates are no longer active here.

Comment: @kenorb I recently discovered that [nbro resigned after being suspended on CrossValidated.SE](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1681/19524). If you do run again for election, I would upvote you, as I remember you from Area51 and the Paranormal Factor chat room.